# Possible to run Python Script in terminal to process PayNow payment?

Tags: python, payment

PayNow is a service (available in Singapore) that allows you to send to and receive money using a mobile number or Singapore NRIC without having to know the recipient's account number.

Some reference:

1. https://www.ocbc.com/personal-banking/help-and-support/paynow.html
2. https://www.dbs.com/developers/

Below is how I imagine PayNow payment (**transfer using recipient's registered mobile number**) could be process using a python script - i took reference from Paypal and modified inputs according to what I saw on DBS Developer's document.

**What i am trying to achieve:** With a list of mobile numbers, I am able to process PayNow payments to the recipients in batches/ bulk. But for now, I'm just wondering how to process a PayNow payment by running a python script.

**My questions are:**

1. is the below script right?
2. is there a library i can import and documentations i can read?
3. I understand that there's some API calling and redirect URI, how does it fit into this?
4. I am hoping to just run a python script from the terminal to process the payment. It is not an app. So how do i get the ClientID, ClientSecret and token?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

---

```
import paynow

paynowrestsdk.configure({
  "mode": "sandbox", # sandbox or live
  "client_id": "EBWKjlELKMYqRNQ6sYvFo64FtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM",
  "client_secret": "EO422dn3gQLgDbuwqTjzrFgFtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM" })

payment = paynowrestsdk.Payment({
            "fundTransferDetl”:{
            “partyId":"11845277752388953651",
            "debitAccountId":"21841900319944140151001",
            "payeeReference":{
                "referenceType":"MSISDN",
                "referenceDesc":"Mobile no.",
                "reference":"65998899758"
            },
            "amount":5,
            "transferCurrency":"SGD",
            "comments":"Transfer",
            "purpose":"Transfer",
            "referenceId":"4P3EDAB1C853A004117A330"
            }
            })

if payment.create():
  print(referenceId)
  print(status)
else:
  print(payment.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to run python program in terminal, just pass your arguements to it:

```
python script.py --client_id EBWKjlELKMYqRNQ6sYvFo64FtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM`
```

Then in program, use the `argparse` package to parse arguments

Answer (score 0):

According to the OCBC API documentation, it only works if the sender is an OCBC account holder. I'd assume likewise for the DBS one. To date, I am still unable to find an universal API for do